# "Make items available" removes items from selected squad

Tags: xcom-2

When I equip my squad for a mission, and say use "Make weapon available", it removes the items on my selected squad, both armor and utilities. The ingame text says that it's supposed to remove items from soldiers not selected for the mission. However, it seems to make no distinction from selected or unselected soldiers.

Is this something that anyone has experienced?

Comment: This seems more like a rant than an actual question. Maybe you'd like to edit your question?

Comment: When I click "Make utility items available", it does not remove the medkit that I have assigned to a member of my squad. I can't try "make weapons available" because I'm too early in the game and don't have upgraded weapons yet :)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the following bugs at the mission prep screen during my playthrough:

- The Make X available buttons overlap. Sometimes the buttons does not displayed at the correct position and instead they are overlapping each other.
- Functionality switch-up. Sometimes the Make armor Available button makes the Utility items available, or vica-versa. Thankfully the Alarm message before the action states correctly what are you trying to remove.
- Make X available doesn't makes some of the equipment available on not selected soldiers.
- **Make X available removes equipment from selected soldiers.** I have only seen this very few times but it happened to me too.

Frankly those buttons are bugged to hell, I would advice that instead of relying on them just manage your items manually. You can switch in healthy soldiers to remove their equipment, or you can just escape from the mission prep screen and manage the inventory in the Armory / Soldiers screen.